# Installation fails with "failed to partition: /cdrom" error

Tags: system-installation

I am having a problem installing ubuntu 11, after booting from my usb flash I get an error saing "failed to partition: /cdrom", if I press continue the instalation gets stuck in detecting system files, I tried to boot from a cd rom but the problem persists.

Is this a common error? Any solution?

Comment: I think we'll need a bit more information.  How did you create the bootable USB drive?  And does it at least start with some Ubuntu stuff, like a screen giving you installation options?  And still at the beginning, does your computer's BIOS allow you to boot from a USB drive?

Comment: Also: How much do you know about partitioning disks, and what partitions have what installed (use the 'gparted' program on a live CD to find out)?

Comment: This sounds like another instance that could be solved by:

http://askubuntu.com/a/243144/59365

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the normal/recommended tools to make the Ubuntu install usb? It's just a hunch, but have you tried installing Ubuntu from a CD?