# Trouble Installing 12.10 on a GA-990FXA-UD3 Base Machine: Network and USB Don't Work

Tags: networking, drivers, 64-bit, uefi

I've spent two days pulling my hair out trying to get Ubuntu to install correctly on a new machine I built using a Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 motherboard.

Ubuntu seems to install fine, however, neither the network nor USB 3.0 drivers work out of the box.  The board has a Realtek 8111E chip and to fix the network I've been trying to download and install the Realtek r8168-8.035.00 driver.  I was able to get the driver on to the machine by swapping out the mouse, keyboard and USB stick from the two working USB 2.0 ports.  However, it won't compile.  I get the following error:

```
Build the module and install
make: *** /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

I found a thread from a failed upgrade that suggests you can solve this by using apt-get to reinstall the kernel package.  So I downloaded the kernel package from a net capable laptop, moved it over to the machine on a USB drive and reinstalled it.  That fixed the compile error and the driver seemed to install fine from there.

But still no dice connecting to the net after install.

I haven't even started trying to tackle the USB controller drivers.  Has anyone had any success getting Ubuntu to play nice with this Mobo?  What did you have to do?

Comment: Try to use a PCIe network card until you get your hands on a working Realtek 8111E driver for your motherboard, seen it in [this thread](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?60433-Gigabyte-GA-990FXA-UD3-for-Ubuntu).

Comment: Please update with any solution. I am in the same boat right now.

Comment: @Nicholas Never found one.  That machine is currently an oversized paperweight.  I've been using a spare laptop while I try to decide what to do with it.

Comment: @DanielBingham, just letting you know that GUERIN's solution actually worked for me. You should check it out.

Comment: Daniel, could you accept GUERIN's answer? I almost dismissed his response if I had not seen Nicholas Mancuso's "HOLY SH*T" below it. @NicholasMancuso: Thank you! Good way to get my attention :) As stated below, that solved my problems with the board and 13.10.

Comment: @hknust I remember trying a solution similar to that when I was working on this to no avail.  But that was two releases ago, so let me try again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to your Bios <kbd>suppr</kbd> or <kbd>del</kbd> when you turn on your computer, and when in Bios look for "network stack" and set it to "enable."

Also look for "iommu controller"  and set it to "enable."

Press <kbd>f10</kbd> to save and reset.

Maybe go on to the Realtek web site and download Linux drivers:

http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=5&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2

Comment: Thanks GUERIN!!! I had the same issues that Daniel experienced (minus the build problem). Just installing the 8168 driver was not enough. Once I changed the BIOS settings everything lit up and the USB ports started working again.

Comment: Someone queue the Hallelujah chorus!  That was all it took.  Incredible.  Sorry it took me so long to accept, I've been using a laptop and having taken the time to go back to fiddling with the tower until now.

Comment: After IOMMU is enabled, USB3 ports stop working. The madness continues.