# Ubuntu server installer says it can't find CD drive, but the server doesn't have a CD drive

Tags: server, system-installation, usb

The server I just built does not have a CD drive. I want to install Ubuntu Server 12.10.

The motherboard in the server is a Gigabyte GA-H61M-USB3. I burned the image to a thumb drive and set up the BIOS to boot from USB (USB-CDROM setting). The installer launches and I am able to do the initial setup (language, keyboard, etc.), but then I get an error saying that it can't find the CD drive.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem twice; the OS was booting just fine from USB but for some reason it was trying to load files from the CD-ROM.

The fiest time I re-downloaded the image and burned into USB again and the second I followed the procedure mentioned in [USB drive install of Ubuntu 12.04 Server fails - can't find components from CD-ROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127398/usb-drive-install-of-ubuntu-12-04-server-fails-cant-find-components-from-cd-r/243144#243144)