# Booting Ubuntu with a USB without CD-ROM detection

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, usb

I am using the unetbootin application to create a bootable USB for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. However, when booting the server the installer menu wants to detect and mount the CD-ROM, which i don't have. So the installation fails, because it will not get pass the CD-ROM.  How do I and What do I change to skip/override the detection of the CR-ROM and continue to use the USB to build the Ubuntu 12.04 Server LTS?

And please be specific, I am learning Ubuntu / Linux nomenclature so I am no where close to an expert on the linguistics.

Sheriff

Comment: Change the boot order by giving first priority to usb in bios.

Comment: This is a duplicate. You can see a solution here that I think is easiest; other possible solutions are discussed in the thread: https://askubuntu.com/a/243144/59365

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the boot order in your BIOS settings. When you boot up, there will be a small note on the screen telling you which key to press for the BIOS settings (often but not always `F10`). Once in the BIOS settings menu, navigate to change the boot order and make sure the USB drive is preferred.

Comment: I have disabled the DC drive in the BIOS boot order menu. I need to know where in the folders and files to pint the query for the CD-ROM back to the USB.

Comment: @Sheriff I'm not sure what you mean about folders and files but here is a [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/129815/) on changing the boot order.