# Installation problem Lubuntu-13.10

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, wubi

I'm trying to install Lubuntu-13.10 onto my laptop as the XP operating system replacement. Vale XP. Laptop is ASUS. System type X86-based PC, processor 1596Mhz, Total physical memory 512MB, Available physical memory 216MB.

I unzip the .iso file from the CD drive. I click on wubi.exe and it all looks to be going well. Full green bar for 'Installing Lubuntu-13.10'. 1/5 green bar for 'Remaining time approximately 0s', then this error mesage: "An error occurred: No such file or directory. For more information, please see the log file: c:\docume~1\admini~1\locals~1\temp\wubi-13.10-rev284.log"

Any help greatly appreciated. Gav

Comment: Can you upload the log file? (on paste.ubuntu.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to completely replace XP with Lubuntu 13.10 I would recommend to just make a bootable usb-stick with rufus (as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/429899/253889)) and then just boot via usb.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu has better answers on how to install via usb. Linking sources outside of AU isn't a good choice since they can disappear at any moment.

Comment: The source I refer to is inside AU. Only the download link for rufus is external. But you got a point that the answer you refer to is very detailed. But I'm not quite sure if just burning the .iso-image onto a dvd makes it bootable.

Comment: I also meant that the other guide has screenshots and cover all install parts, which your answer doesn't. but just as long as the OP is happy! ;)

Comment: Thanks JLJ and Alvar. Have made bootable usb-stick with Rufus and will atempt to make WinXP disappear! Gav

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that Ubuntu 12.04 was the last supported version under WUBI so you may not be able to install it and Microsoft Windows XP is due to stop getting security updates in a couple of weeks.  That means that you computer will be vulnerable.  Plus no patches for applications will be released.  Recommend that you install Ubuntu directly after you back up your data.  It is a better option and if you wait a couple of weeks the new Ubuntu version will be released.

Comment: Thanks Rex. Miracle of miracles! Managed to install Lubuntu! Running it at present alongside WinXP.