# After entering BusyBox during Ubuntu Server 14.04 install process, how can I leave it?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, busybox

I entered the BusyBox console from the 'Select Language' screen using using Alt + F2 and now I want to return to the install process.  If I type 'exit' I can get back to 'Please press Enter to activate this console.' but if I press 'Alt + F2' nothing happens.  I have also tried with Ctrl and Ctrl + Alt F6.

The reason for all this is I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 14.04 on a Dell R410 using a USB stick but, for some reason, the installer gets stuck trying to load files off a CD drive that doesn't exist.  To try and fix this I am following the instructions in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/130826

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I discovered that the install itself runs from within BusyBox (ash), not vice versa.  So to 'return' to the installer one can run

```
/sbin/debian-installer
```

Edit: I have since discovered Alt + F1 also works.